# three.js: How to extrude a shape defined by an image file

Tags: javascript, three.js, shapes

How can I replace the hearts with the leaf provided?

I'm building this web app, with *falling objects* using Three.JS.
I found a shape of a heart to get myself started, but now I need to replace that shape with an autumn leaf (that's the only thing to do, actually).

This is the image:
[image]

I don't quite understand how shapes work in that regard.

Try it yourself:

```js
'use strict';

var container, stats;
var camera, scene, renderer;
var group,
    shapes = [];
init();

function init() {
  container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(0, 150, 500);
  scene.add(camera);

  var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x9955ff, 2);
  light.position.x = -500;
  light.position.y = 500;
  camera.add(light);

  var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x9955ff, 1);
  light.position.x = 500;
  light.position.y = -500;
  light.position.z = -150;
  camera.add(light);

  scene.background = new THREE.Color('#993355');

  var x = -25,
      y = -250;
  var heartShape = new THREE.Shape();
  heartShape.moveTo(x + 25, y + 25);
  heartShape.bezierCurveTo(x + 25, y + 25, x + 20, y, x, y);
  heartShape.bezierCurveTo(x - 30, y, x - 30, y + 35, x - 30, y + 35);
  heartShape.bezierCurveTo(x - 30, y + 55, x - 10, y + 77, x + 25, y + 95);
  heartShape.bezierCurveTo(x + 60, y + 77, x + 80, y + 55, x + 80, y + 35);
  heartShape.bezierCurveTo(x + 80, y + 35, x + 80, y, x + 50, y);
  heartShape.bezierCurveTo(x + 35, y, x + 25, y + 25, x + 25, y + 25);

  var extrudeSettings = { amount: 1, bevelEnabled: true, bevelSegments: 20, steps: 2, bevelSize: 20, bevelThickness: 10 };

  for (var i = -window.innerWidth / 2; i < window.innerWidth / 2; i += 60 + Math.random() * 50) {
    for (var j = 0; j < window.innerHeight; j += 60 + Math.random() * 50) {
      addShape(heartShape, extrudeSettings, '#ff0022', i, j, 0, Math.random() * 0.8, Math.random() * 0.8, Math.PI, 0.1 + Math.random() * 0.3);
    }
  }

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  render();
}

function addShape(shape, extrudeSettings, color, x, y, z, rx, ry, rz, s) {
  var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(shape, extrudeSettings);
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: color }));
  mesh.position.set(x + 25, y - 50, z);
  mesh.rotation.set(rx, ry, rz);
  mesh.scale.set(s, s, s);
  shapes.push({ shape: mesh, x: Math.random(), y: Math.random(), z: Math.random() });
  scene.add(mesh);
}

function animate() {
  var speed = 0.05;
  shapes.forEach(function (el) {
    el.shape.rotation.x += el.x * speed;
    el.shape.rotation.y += el.y * speed;
    el.shape.rotation.z += el.z * speed;
  });
}

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  animate();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r79/three.min.js'></script>
```

It needs to be the same, exactly the same. Only the hearts needs to be replaced by leafs.

Comment: It's maybe easier to model the shape in Blender, export to `glTF` and then load the asset via `GLTFLoader`. BTW: Since your geometry and material settings are equal for all meshes, create the geometry and material once and reuse them. Updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bydwzr

Comment: Tip: I'd advise against using a version of three.js that is 3 years old. Update to the current version.

Answer (score 4):

You want to extrude a shape defined by an image file.

First, use an online image converter such as https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg to convert your file to SVG format. (In your case, you will then have to manually edit the generated SVG file to remove the bounding circle.) You can define the SVG contents as a string if you want.

```
var text = `<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="800.000000pt" height="800.000000pt" viewBox="0 0 800.000000 800.000000"
 preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<metadata>
Created by potrace 1.15, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2017
</metadata>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,800.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="m311 -1104 c9 -47 29 -114 44 -150 53 -126 236 -481 250 -487 8 -3
27 2 41 12 41 27 50 15 57 -77 10 -147 47 -198 142 -198 30 0 44 7 71 36 19
19 38 33 44 29 20 -12 22 -79 5 -182 -27 -165 -5 -311 70 -468 42 -88 66 -104
131 -87 60 16 213 86 529 242 207 102 277 142 342 194 45 36 87 66 93 66 20 0
5 -54 -100 -375 -108 -330 -125 -398 -118 -480 6 -70 27 -95 80 -95 50 0 58
-20 24 -63 -104 -128 -106 -132 -106 -170 0 -53 37 -88 125 -117 76 -24 98
-39 87 -56 -4 -6 -52 -41 -107 -77 -157 -102 -225 -186 -225 -276 0 -53 37
-96 112 -128 32 -14 58 -32 58 -40 0 -25 -103 -62 -343 -122 -313 -79 -327
-87 -267 -152 39 -44 26 -58 -38 -40 -77 20 -522 215 -740 323 -138 69 -206
98 -213 91 -7 -7 -2 -48 15 -130 14 -66 42 -212 63 -324 36 -198 37 -211 38
-436 l0 -233 -30 -29 c-43 -43 -109 -58 -157 -38 -48 20 -81 71 -73 112 3 17
30 71 60 120 30 50 61 110 70 134 17 50 19 165 4 231 -6 25 -35 161 -64 304
-29 142 -58 263 -64 269 -8 8 -27 4 -68 -12 -112 -45 -340 -160 -538 -271
-214 -121 -410 -220 -431 -220 -20 0 -17 10 16 59 63 93 50 98 -280 104 -228
4 -276 7 -342 25 -101 27 -218 74 -216 87 1 6 20 15 43 20 63 17 103 46 207
153 114 118 134 160 103 219 -15 28 -38 44 -114 81 l-96 46 48 6 c57 7 67 19
67 82 0 37 -12 70 -66 175 -79 154 -131 234 -218 333 l-65 75 32 3 c40 4 53
15 60 50 3 15 -7 133 -23 263 -45 365 -54 488 -41 537 14 50 27 54 36 10 30
-142 186 -273 524 -443 287 -143 369 -164 401 -100 21 43 25 177 7 263 -8 39
-13 81 -10 92 5 19 7 18 25 -11 18 -30 21 -31 70 -27 94 9 148 97 148 239 0
79 29 114 58 69 17 -28 54 -25 85 8 32 33 73 123 82 177 12 74 15 85 30 85 8
0 15 -4 15 -10 0 -16 25 -11 53 10 26 20 31 33 62 145 l17 60 14 -28 c8 -15
18 -27 22 -27 21 0 58 41 118 131 74 111 131 233 163 354 38 137 42 146 59
143 11 -2 21 -27 33 -88z"/>
</g>
</svg>`;
```

Then, use `THREE.SVGLoader` to parse the file and extrude it.

```
var data = new THREE.SVGLoader().parse( text );

var paths = data.paths;

var shapes = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < paths.length; i ++ ) {

    Array.prototype.push.apply( shapes, paths[ i ].toShapes() ); // catenate, so we can create a single geometry and mesh

}

var extrusionSettings = {
    depth: 20,
    bevelEnabled: false
};

var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry( shapes, extrusionSettings );
geometry.center();

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh.scale.y *= - 1;

scene.add( mesh );
```

`SVGLoader` is located in the `threejs/examples/jsm/loaders/` directory and must be included in your project.

[image: rendering of extruded shape]

three.js r153

Comment: Thank you, @WestLangley, this was helpful! Howered, do you have a CodePen of what you did? Because I'm trying to implement it in the scene and throws "THREE.SVGLoader is not a constructor", although I manually imported.

Comment: CodePen, no. Does [this](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_svg.html) three.js `SVGLoader` example work for you?